# Озвучивание текста в iOS приложении (Swift)

Tags: swift

Ищу способы как реализовать чтение текста в "TextField" голосом, наподобие "TwitchAlerts" или озвучивание у "Google Translator". Может кто подскажет какие то фреймворки или направит на нужную статью. Не нашел ничего подходящего на GitHub и англо-версии Stackoverflow. Заранее благодарю!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте для этого [AVSpeechSynthesizer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avspeechsynthesizer).
В работе очень прост. Маленький пример:

```
import AVKit
...
let synthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: "Привет. Это пример.")
utterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "ru-RU")
synthesizer.speak(utterance)
```

Статьи можете поискать которые подойдут Вам по запросу "AVSpeechSynthesizer".

Comment: Благодарю вас !